# How do I address imbalanced data before training?

Tags: python, opencv, dataset, detection, yolo

Suppose that we want to train YOLOV3. We gathered around 5000 images for 3 different classes. Class distribution is:

```
Class#1 = 2250  images
Class #2= 2500  images
Class #3= 250   images
```

As you can see it is imbalanced and I can not train based on that data. What do I need to do? do I need to consider a data processing stage?

Please do not merely say data augmentation, as data augmentation has a different meaning. I believe it does rotation and transformation during the training and makes the trained model more robust, it doesn't solve an imbalanced data set issue.

How do I address imbalanced data?

Comment: there are several ways. You could try to duplicate samples or remove other samples or if the framework allows it: Balance each minibatch. From my experience, yolo works quite ok with imbalanced set, maybe because often different object classes fall in different anchors. Maybe imbalanced set is in general not that much of a problem in object detection (compared zo classification), but that's just a guess.

Comment: Did you look at [smote](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-smote-for-dealing-with-imbalanced-image-dataset-for-solving-classification-problems-3aba7d2b9cad)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the following to your config file:

**Choice 1:**

```
[yolo]
focal_loss=1
```

**Choice 2** (more effective):

```
[yolo]
counters_per_class=100, 2000, 300, ... # number of objects per class in your Training dataset
```

To calculate the counters_per_class, refer to this [link](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/4792#issuecomment-610583784)

More details [here](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/4792)

**Choice 3:** Do both Choice 1 & Choice 2

Answer (score 0):

for yolov7, you can :

- Adjust the focal loss with the parameter : h['fl_gamma']